# Intellj scala and Java 10: Error:scalac: 'jvm-1.10' is not a valid choice for '-target'

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I'm trying to compile one of our project on intellij in gradle project with scala 2.12 ant JDK 10.

gradle builds fine from command line, but Intellij fails with:

```
Error:scalac: 'jvm-1.10' is not a valid choice for '-target'
Error:scalac: bad option: '-target:jvm-1.10'
```

I've tried setting config as suggested in other answers, but that does not seem to help

```
tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    sourceCompatibility = "1.10"
    targetCompatibility = "1.10"
    scalaCompileOptions.metaClass.useAnt = false
 }
```

So clearly I am missing some setting in Intellij , but which one?

Answer (score 0):

Check this setting:

Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle

The chosen JVM should be at least version 10